# Installing Python packages in a Pyspark EMR bootstrap

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-emr

I would like to install my EMR dependencies in a bootstrap script. When I attempt to start a cluster with my script, I get a warning from pip saying that

> An error was encountered:
>
> No module named 'great_expectations'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'great_expectations'

What should I change with my shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
sudo pip install --user \
  pandas==0.25.1         \
  awscli                 \
  boto3                  \
  great_expectations
```

Comment: I will convert it to answer later, can you try with pip3? Might be the case that python3 is being used instead of python2.7